# How do I add an additional option with long press on a contact of my contact list of my android application?

Tags: android, contacts, long-press

I have developed an android application of call blocking, it is working nice . But I want to add an additional option on it. Such as, when an user will long press on one of his contact number , one additional option with appear beside the options named call block, that option will help him to add that number directly to the block list. I have no idea how to customize the long press option of a contact. After long press on a contact number of my mobile this options  appear 
 [image]

I want one additional option , that will refer my software

[image]

Want to add this Call Block option with this view , so that I can add a number directly from here in to my application call block list.

Answer (score 0):

You cant add options in another app